# converting daily timeseries into monthly in R

Tags: r

I have tried to convert the daily values into monthly average in R. But, all columns of the avrage become the same values. Help ASAP. Here is the code and some result.

gewane$month <- lubridate::month(gewane$Date)

> gewane$year <- lubridate::year(gewane$Date)
> head(gewane)

```
        Date Precipitation month year
1 1979-01-01    0.00000000     1 1979
2 1979-01-02    0.00000000     1 1979
3 1979-01-03    0.02059937     1 1979
4 1979-01-04    0.00000000     1 1979
5 1979-01-05    0.00000000     1 1979
6 1979-01-06    0.00000000     1 1979
```

> library(dplyr)
> gewane %>%

- group_by(year,month) %>%
- summarize(averPR = mean(gewane$Precipitation))
  `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

  ## A tibble: 427 x 3

  ## Groups:   year [36]

  ```
    year month averPR
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
  ```

  1  1979     1  0.673
  2  1979     2  0.673
  3  1979     3  0.673
  4  1979     4  0.673
  5  1979     5  0.673
  6  1979     6  0.673
  7  1979     7  0.673
  8  1979     8  0.673
  9  1979     9  0.673
  10  1979    10  0.673

  ## ... with 417 more rows

Comment: Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes. `.....summarize(averPR = mean(Precipitation))`

Comment: thank you very much. You saved me alot of time.